# Construct a compact set of real numbers whose limit points form a countable set? (Rudin Exercise)

Tags: real-analysis

I think $S = \{r \in \Bbb Q: 0 \leq r \leq 1\}$ in $\Bbb R$ can be a set that satisfies the conditions. First, it is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem since it is closed and bounded. It is closed because it contains all its limit points. Every rational number is a limit point; if we take an open neighbourhood of radius s, we can find some rational number contained in the open ball. Finally, the rationals are countable.

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not. As limit points you get the whole interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand.

Comment: If you can find a set in $[0,1]$ with only one limit point, then you can use scaling to define one in $[1, 1.5]$, $[1.5, 1.75]$....

Comment: Your set $S$ is not closed.

Comment: In the example where the integers are a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, the set of integers is trivially closed because every point in the integers was not a limit point. So would the complement of the rationals, the irrationals, be similar; trivially closed? (Immediately before and after an irrational is a rational). So would it be open then?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444591/construct-a-compact-set-of-real-numbers-whose-limit-points-form-a-countable-set).

Comment: Thanks, David. I saw that but wanted to try my own. :) I'll take a look again.

Answer (score -1):

What about $\{\frac 1n:n\in Z^+\} \cup \{0\}$?

Comment: Why isn't the set $\{ 0 \}$ already a solution?

Comment: I think countably infinite was meant.

Comment: I think {0} isn't a solution because it doesn't satisfy the definition of countable according to Rudin.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That looks like it would do. It's closed and bounded and the mapping n to 1/n works so it is countable.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just wanted to be sure that the wikipedia definition is not the only one.

Comment: @August You are welcome!